# quick liquid shows a black box on 3d viewport

Tags: 3d-view, fluid-simulation

I can't seem to figure out why it shows a black box in 3d viewport.
I followed a [quick liquid tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3mhJXuveFo) and I used a quick liquid function from the <kbd>F3</kbd> menu, after changing the liquid from geometry to inflow it looked nice and so I went over to the 3d viewport and it's all just a black box. I tried putting lights and re-baking it but nothing worked.

This is how it looks in 3d viewport:
[image: this is how it looks in 3d viewport]

And this is how it looks in wireframe mode:
[image: and this is how it looks in wireframe mode]

I don't know how to reply to the guy who commented on me so I'll just put the domain material here:
[image: material]

Comment: You have baked no mesh, there is only fluid data as particles. And what about your domain material, can you add a screenshot too? This complete blackness looks like you have no shader nodes or anything.

Comment: provide your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: @Chris https://www.mediafire.com/file/j6gwgerr1qhkr4j/quickliquidhelp.blend/file

Comment: Is this the correct file? You said you changed _Geometry_ to _Inflow_, but the file still has a fluid object set to _Geometry_. And on my system it doesn't look black. But as I said before, you haven't baked the mesh - so whatever you do to make it not look black anymore, it will still look like a cuboid and not a liquid if you don't bake the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

1. if you follow a tutorial and you are a bloody beginner you SHOULD exactly follow the tutorial because every little step is important and cold ruin your whole simulation
2. as i could see in your blend file ...you didn't follow the tutorial at all...
3. to get "something" change these settings:

- change cache type to "replay"

[image]

- change viewport shading to material preview

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

Comment: ohhhh thank you very much <3

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Please consider to accept the answer @Moogle How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

About the **blackness** here. [That's a bug in Blender 2.93](https://developer.blender.org/T88754) when *Roughness* value is set to a very low value (0.003...) and you have an Intel UHD Graphics unit or another affected GPU.

In Blender 2.92 it looks as it should:
[image: liquid domain in Blender 2.92]
<sup>liquid domain in Blender 2.92 with *Roughness* set to 0.000</sup>